# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in laravel ...is there something i'm missing?

Tags: laravel, forms, pusher

blade file :

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/admin/sender')}}"method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit">


</form>
```

Controller:

```
   public function notificationSender(Request $request)
    {
        $text= request()->text;
        print_r($request->input());
        event(new OrderComplete($text));
        return view('admin.sender');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/sender','HomeController@notificationSender');
```

the route is a subroute for a group..is there something i'm missing?

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` to check for your routes. and also inspect the route generated in the form by `{{URL::to('/admin/sender')}}` is same as the routes you have. its better to not use a relative route and using a named route.

Comment: php artisan route:list and put route lsit

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give space between method and route parameters here

if your laravel version is 5 then use this

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/admin/sender')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or else you can also name the route to make it easy to pass in action parameter of form like this.

```
Route::post('/sender','HomeController@notificationSender')->name('sender');
```

Then you can pass it in form like this

```
   <form action="{{route('sender')}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For GET Method (Laravel 6)

blade file

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('sender') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
@csrf

    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit">


</form>
```

Write Controller

```
public function notificationSender(Request $request)
    {
        $text= $request->get('text');
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($text);
        event(new OrderComplete($text));
        return view('admin.sender');
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('sender','HomeController@notificationSender');
```